# <form> sending null to controller when the inputs are inside a component

Tags: php, laravel, forms, laravel-8, laravel-blade

im working in laravel and i got a problem that i dont understand, i have this component that uses recursions to build a whole form from a json stored in a table:

```
@foreach($data as $index => $field)
    @isset($lastIndex)
        @php
        $name = $template->slug."%%".$field['key']."%%".$lastIndex 
        @endphp
    @endisset

    @if($field['type'] == 'object')

        <div class="card border card-border-light justify-content-center">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row mb-3">
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                        <label class="form-label">{{$field['label']}}</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        @component('components.templates.templateForm', [
                            'template' => $template,
                            'data' => $field['data'],
                            'disabled' => $disabled,
                            'lastIndex' => $field['key'],
                            ])
                        @endcomponent
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    @elseif($field['type'] == 'string')
        <div class="row mb-3">
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label for="hero_title" class="form-label">{{$field['label']}}</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input name="{{$name ?? $template->slug."%%".$field['key']}}" class="form-control"
                       value="{{$name ?? $template->slug."%%".$field['key']}}" id="hero_title"
                       placeholder="Titulo do banner" {{$disabled ? 'disabled' : ''}}>
            </div>
        </div>

    @elseif($field['type'] == 'text')
        <div class="row mb-3">
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label for="hero_title" class="form-label">{{$field['label']}}</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <textarea name="{{$name ?? $template->slug."%%".$field['key']}}" class="form-control"
                  id="hero_title"
                  placeholder="Titulo do banner"  {{$disabled ? 'disabled' : ''}}>{{$name ?? $template->slug."%%".$field['key']}}</textarea>
            </div>
        </div>

    @elseif($field['type'] == 'image')
        <div class="row mb-3">
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label for="hero_title" class="form-label">{{$field['label']}}</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input name="{{$name ?? $template->slug."%%".$field['key']}}" class="form-control"
                       id="hero_title" value="{{$name ?? $template->slug."%%".$field['key']}}"
                       placeholder="Titulo do banner" {{$disabled ? 'disabled' : ''}} >
                <div class="row mb-3" style='margin:10px;'>
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                        <label for="hero_title" class="form-label">Preview:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <img
                            src="https://site-.s3.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/5/2023/06/19134118/logo-unicamp.png"
                            alt='image' class="images-table-list">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    @endif
@endforeach
```

and then i use this component as the inputs to my form

```
<form action="{{ route('templates.store') }}" method="POST">
                @csrf
                    @component('components.templates.templateForm', [
                                'template' => $template,
                                'data' => $data,
                                'disabled' => true,

                                ])
                    @endcomponent
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
                </form>
```

however when i go to the store method on my controller, and dd() the $request->all() i get only the @csrf field and nothing else does anyone know why?

placing an input directly on the form resolves it, but that shouldnt be the case, doesnt the component just builds the form? my suspicion is that the form is being made before the component, so when the component finishes building the inputs, the form already made itself, forgetting the component.but i really dont know.

Answer (score 0):

yeah im dumb, the problem is that disabled fields as the name sugests, are DISABLED, and thus are ignored by the form, sorry for wasting stackoverflow memory on this.